# Powershell: Move all files except most recently modified?

Tags: powershell

Trying to simplify one of my archiving tasks, but I'm stumped on how to go about it. Basically, I just want Powershell to search a folder for files, and move all but the most recently modified (by LastWriteTime) to a backup folder.

I've searched around for solutions to this but every answer I've come across looks for the oldest file or depends on a specific file-naming convention to work.

Basically I want it to look at this this:
E:\ProjectFolder1\EDLs\File1.prproj (modified six days ago)
E:\ProjectFolder1\EDLs\File2.prproj (modified six hours ago)
E:\ProjectFolder1\EDLs\File3.prproj (modified six seconds ago)

Identify File3.prproj as the one that's most up-to-date, and move all the other files in the directory to another folder:

E:\Deep Storage\ProjectFolder1\EDLs\File1.prproj
E:\Deep Storage\ProjectFolder1\EDLs\File2.prproj

I know how to do everything except get it to compare the LastWriteTimes. Is there a way do get PS to do this?

EDIT with code sample

```
Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Include $search -Recurse | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | `
    foreach{ 
        $targetFile = $targetDir + $_.FullName.SubString($sourceDir.Length); 
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force;  
        Move-Item $_.FullName -destination $targetFile -Force
    }
```

EDIT with functional code:

```
$sourceDir = "E:\Test1\EDLs\"
$targetDir = "E:\Deep Storage\Test1\EDLs\"
$search = "*.prproj"

Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $files = $_ | Get-ChildItem -File -Filter $search
    if($files.Count -lt 2) {
        return
    }

    $newPath = Join-Path $targetDir -ChildPath $_.FullName.Substring($sourceDir.Length)
    $null = New-Item $newPath -ItemType Directory -Force
    $files | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        Move-Item -Destination $newPath -Verbose -WhatIf
    }
```

EDIT to show actual syntax for operating environment:

```
$sourceDir = "E:\Projects\Current\EDLs"
$targetDir = "E:\Deep Storage\Projects\Current\EDLs"
$search = "*.prproj"

Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Directory | ForEach-Object {
# search only for files only 1 level under this folder
$files = Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Filter *.prproj
# if there are at least 2 files here
if($files.Count -ge 2) {
    # we dont need to create new folder here since these will go directly under
    # destination folder so, we can just sort and skip first as in previous logic
    $files | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        # then move them
        Move-Item -Destination $targetDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the answer was a lot simpler than I thought it would be:

```
$sourceDir="E:\Test1\Test2"
# Where your files are

$targetDir="E:\Deep Storage\Test1\Test2"
# Where you want to send them

$search="*.ext"
# If applicable, what type of file you want to look for

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Filter $search | Sort-Object |
    Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | Move-Item -Destination $targetDir -Verbose -WhatIf
```

I use environment variables for my workflow so mine looks a little different, but this should be useful for anyone in the same situation.

Comment: You are not sorting on property LastWriteTime, so the sorting will be done on the file NAME which does not match the title of your question _"except most recently modified?"_